# Opening python .dat in objective-c

Tags: python, objective-c, database

I am making an app for iOS that uses .dat database files created using 
python scripts .

How can I get my data out of the databases using objective-c or c ??

I have no experience with python , 
i guess it has a S/N column and a Passwords one .

this is the code : [here](http://www.mentalpitstop.com/touchspeedcalc/touchspeedcalc_createtable.py)

Comment: You guess it does? This is a somewhat vague question - have you looked at the data? What format is it in? Python can be used to generate data in whatever format the developer desires, do you have access to the code that produced the data, or ask someone responsible for production of the data for the format?

Comment: @JonClements I have added the link to the script

Comment: Okay thanks. Had a look at that, and put what you've got as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the posted Python code - it creates various variables, but only writes out one called `ssid` which happens to be the last 3 bytes of a sha1 digest.

The file it writes to is not opened in binary mode but has binary data written to it, so some funny things with EOLs may occur.

Otherwise, to retrieve your data, keep reading 3 bytes at a time from the file...

Comment: Yeah ... How can I do that in C or objective-c ?? :)